# Split large XML into smaller files based on chunks of child nodes using unix script

Tags: xml, bash, perl, shell, unix

I could do the same thing in java or c# with ease but doing this in shell scripting involves lot of learning...so any help is appreciated

I have a huge xml node with child nodes like URL (lets say 100K nodes) and I need to split the input.xml with 10K nodes in each subfile,so I get 10 files containing 10K nodes with parent tag in tact (URLSet tab).

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

<url>
  <loc> https://www.mywebsite.com/shopping </loc>
  <changefreq> Weekly </changefreq>
  <priority> 0.8 </priority>
  <lastmod> 2016-09-22 </lastmod>
</url>
<url>
  <loc> https://www.mywebsite.com/shopping </loc>
  <changefreq> Weekly </changefreq>
  <priority> 0.8 </priority>
  <lastmod> 2016-09-22 </lastmod>
</url>
<url>
  <loc> https://www.mywebsite.com/shopping </loc>
  <changefreq> Weekly </changefreq>
  <priority> 0.8 </priority>
  <lastmod> 2016-09-22 </lastmod>
</url>
<url>
  <loc> https://www.mywebsite.com/shopping </loc>
  <changefreq> Weekly </changefreq>
  <priority> 0.8 </priority>
  <lastmod> 2016-09-22 </lastmod>
</url>
<url>
  <loc> https://www.mywebsite.com/shopping </loc>
  <changefreq> Weekly </changefreq>
  <priority> 0.8 </priority>
  <lastmod> 2016-09-22 </lastmod>
</url>
<url>
  <loc> https://www.mywebsite.com/shopping </loc>
  <changefreq> Weekly </changefreq>
  <priority> 0.8 </priority>
  <lastmod> 2016-09-22 </lastmod>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: Do you want to do this with an XML parser, or just some splitting magic?

Comment: Ideally i have to run this after a data stage job in linux environment. XML parser would be good otherwise with strings and regex it is prone for errors.

Comment: As you have used the Perl tag, http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/tools/xml_split/xml_split seems an option.

Comment: @MartinHonnen no, it doesn't really support that kind of thing. Working with `position()` or `count()` will break it. I haven't found a way to do it with `xmL_split` yet.

Comment: @simbabque, shouldn't the option `-g <nb>`, e.g. `-g 10000` solve it? I am not at a machine with Perl so I can't test and I don't remember for sure I have used it but that sounds like an option to get files with 10k elements.

Comment: @MartinHonnen with a `-g 2` and the example data that will produce the files [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/simbabque/f6642f878719652f77edfc9e77d0441d) –  essentially it splits correctly, but it's meant to be used with `xml_merge` I think.

Comment: Don't do this in `bash`, it doesn't have an XML parser. You could call tools with XML parsers (e.g. `xsltproc`) but I wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is yes, this is totally doable.

`XML::Twig` supports "cut" and "paste" operations, as well as incremental parsing (for lower memory footprint).

So you'd do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

#new document. Manually set xmlns - could copy this from 'original'
#instead though. 
my $new_doc = XML::Twig->new;
$new_doc->set_root(
   XML::Twig::Elt->new(
      'urlset', { xmlns => "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" }
   )
);
$new_doc->set_pretty_print('indented_a');

my $elt_count    = 0;
my $elts_per_doc = 2;
my $count_of_xml = 0;

#handle each 'url' element. 
sub handle_url {
   my ( $twig, $elt ) = @_;
   #more than the count, we output this doc, close it,
   #then create a new one. 
   if ( $elt_count >= $elts_per_doc ) {
      $elt_count = 0;
      open( my $output, '>', "new_xml_" . $count_of_xml++ . ".xml" )
        or warn $!;
      print {$output} $new_doc->sprint;
      close($output);
      $new_doc = XML::Twig->new();
      $new_doc->set_root(
         XML::Twig::Elt->new(
            'urlset',
            { xmlns => "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" }
         )
      );
      $new_doc->set_pretty_print('indented_a');
   }

   #cut this element, paste it into new doc. 
   #note - this doesn't alter the original on disk - only the 'in memory' 
   #copy. 
   $elt->cut;
   $elt->paste( $new_doc->root );
   $elt_count++;
   #purge clears any _closed_ tags from memory, so it preserves 
   #structure.
   $twig->purge;
}

#set a handler, start the parse.

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { 'url' => \&handle_url } ) ->parsefile ( 'your_file.xml' );
```